# Can't fix ModuleNotFoundError (Python)

Tags: python, pip, telegram, modulenotfounderror

I've been trying to run my code for ages and it keeps popping up with this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'

Here is my code:

```
import telegram

api_key = "api_key"
user_id = "id"

class NotificationManager:
    #This class is responsible for sending notifications with the deal flight details.

    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = telegram.Bot(token=api_key)
        pass

    def sendMessage(self, contents):
        self.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=contents)
    pass
```

This code should just send me a message on Telegram when it is run.

Ive tried all solutions i've found online including:

```
pip3 install telegram

pip3 install python-telegram

pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```

Everything is up to date including Python and Pip. I have already tried uninstalling the packages and reinstalling them, which didn't help.

I've even tried reading Chinese and Russian solutions to the problem and they also do nothing (maybe it's just google translate).

Edit:

I am trying to make a program which sends me a message to my Telegram account. There is no further context.

Comment: In case `$ which python` and `$ which pip3` indicate different bin directories, try this: `$ python -m pip install telegram`. That way we're sure to be using the same venv at install time and at run time.

Comment: I just tried this and it still comes up with the error, but 'which python' and 'which pip3' do indicate different bin directories.

Comment: Different directories? Well, that's something you'll want to fix. You're going to find it confusing to have the `pip3` command installing libraries in one directory, when your `python` interpreter reads libraries from a different directory. Carefully adjusting your virtual env variables is a detail you want to get right. You can use `$ python -c 'import telegram'` to quickly verify whether the library is available. It should silently succeed, rather than reporting ModuleNotFoundError. Try importing a built-in library like `sys` and you'll definitely see it succeed.

Comment: I tried ```python -c 'import telegram``` and it succeeded silently which means that it is present. But I still get the modulenotfound error.

Comment: Well, you told us that the very first line of the cool program you run is "import telegram", and that it fails with ModuleNotFoundError. Yet `python -c 'import telegram'` silently succeeds. So I can only conclude that the venv or interpreter being used for `python my_cool_program.py` is different from the one being used for `python -c 'import telegram'`. Figure it out, it's not a hard problem. Output from `$ python -m site` will reveal some helpful debugging info. Let us know what the difficulty was.

Comment: Are you running your code directly from a terminal session or are you in VSCode or some other IDE?

Comment: I've been using vscode alongside a terminal running using ```python3 main.py```. I am in the correct directory as well.